# How to prevent grid.arrange() truncating plots captued with recordPlot()

Tags: r, cowplot, plot-grid

Here is a simplified MWE of my issue. How can I edit the grids or the grid.arrange parameters so that both panels show without truncation?.

[image: Here is the UGLY result]

```
library(cowplot) 

plot(1:5, 1:5)
p1 <- recordPlot()

plot(1:10, 1:10)
p2 <- recordPlot()
grids<-lapply(mget(ls(pattern="p\\d+")),as_grob)
grid.arrange(grobs=grids[1:2],ncol=2)
```

I tried converting each of `p1` and `p2` to grobs with `as_grob()` and then using `grid.edit(grob, vp=viewport(width=0.8, height = 0.8),gPath = grob$name)` but on calling grid.arrange, the grobs still get trunctated.

I also tried changing the margins, or widths, or heights using different combinations of `grid.arrange(grobs=grids[1:2], margins=c(-2,-2,-2)), widths=c(1,1,1,1), heights=c(1,1,1,1))`

Here is the actual image that inspired the MWE, you can see the grid titles being overrun and unreadable when combined
[image]

Comment: playing with mar seems to have solved the problem: 

`par(mfrow=c(2,2),cex.lab=2,mar=c(6,4,4,3))`